# Laravel 5.8: Connect 3 tables throught pivot tables

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, laravel-5.8

I have contacts table where a contact can be a customer or a supplier or both.

In accounts table there is account receivable (AR) and account payable (AP) and other accounts.

Each transaction is recorded in transactions table.

I want to get all contacts (name, email, address, ....) and if the contact is ***customer*** I want to calculate **Sum of the receivables** and if the contact is ***supplier*** I want to calculate **Sum of the payables**.

Models:

Contact

```
  public function transactions() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Transaction');
  }
```

Transaction:

```
  public function accounts()() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account');
  }
```

DB schema
[image]

How to get all contacts info with AR sum and AP sum?

Comment: Would it make sense to have a single table with both "customers" and "suppliers" in it?  And have an extra column that says which (or both).

Comment: @RickJames do you suggest to create 2 separate tables one for suppliers and the other for customers, this approach will force us to create 2 more tables to handle transactions.

Comment: No, one table with both.  A general rule in schema design:  If two tables have a nearly identical set of columns, consider combining them into a single table.

Comment: Another approach is to have 3 tables:  A generic table of contact info (email, etc), plus short, separate tables for Suppliers and Customers.  A way to test each method is to see what the `SELECTs` will look like.

Comment: There is one table "Contacts" that have both customers and suppliers and contact_type column that holds the type of the contact (supplier or customer).

Comment: Bottom line:  "There are multiple ways to skin a cat."